# Redux : TypeError: e[n] is undefined when configuring redux store in reactjs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to the Redux world, so I was following the **Todo List example** of the [redux.js.org](https://redux.js.org) , I tested the [code](https://redux.js.org/basics/exampletodolist) and it works just fine with the redux store having only the reducer as its parameter :

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
import App from "./components/App";

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

as soon as introduce **window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()** as a second parameter to the store in order to be able to use the redux devtools I get this error :
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcsyi.jpg) 
I don't see where I went wrong, I hope you guys could help me figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in the Firefox add-on that has been fixed in version `2.15.4` as explained in [this issue](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/issues/573#issuecomment-439037886), so if you upgrade the add-on it should work as expected.